# Why does GCC call libc's sqrt() without using its result?

Tags: c++, gcc, assembly, x86-64

Using GCC 6.3, the following C++ code:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

void norm(double r, double i)
{
    double n = std::sqrt(r * r + i * i);
    std::cout << "norm = " << n;
}
```

generates the following x86-64 assembly:

```
norm(double, double):
        mulsd   %xmm1, %xmm1
        subq    $24, %rsp
        mulsd   %xmm0, %xmm0
        addsd   %xmm1, %xmm0
        pxor    %xmm1, %xmm1
        ucomisd %xmm0, %xmm1
        sqrtsd  %xmm0, %xmm2
        movsd   %xmm2, 8(%rsp)
        jbe     .L2
        call    sqrt
.L2:
        movl    std::cout, %edi
        movl    $7, %edx
        movl    $.LC1, %esi
        call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, long)
        movsd   8(%rsp), %xmm0
        movl    std::cout, %edi
        addq    $24, %rsp
        jmp     std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::_M_insert<double>(double)
```

For the call to `std::sqrt`, GCC first does it using `sqrtsd` and saves the result on to the stack. If it overflows, it then calls the libc `sqrt` function. But it never saves the `xmm0` after that and before the second call to `operator<<`, it restores the value from the stack (because `xmm0` was lost with the first call to `operator<<`).

With a simpler `std::cout << n;`, it's even more obvious:

```
subq    $24, %rsp
movsd   %xmm1, 8(%rsp)
call    sqrt
movsd   8(%rsp), %xmm1
movl    std::cout, %edi
addq    $24, %rsp
movapd  %xmm1, %xmm0
jmp     std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::_M_insert<double>(double)
```

Why is GCC not using the `xmm0` value computed by libc `sqrt`?

Comment: This is actually a really cool trick they implemented, we finally get the performance of single assembly instructions for calculating transcendental functions in the common case without having to use `-fno-math-errno` and similar.

Comment: `sqrt` is actually algebraic, not transcendental

Answer (score 77, accepted):

It doesn't need to call `sqrt` to compute the result; it's already been calculated by the SQRTSD instruction. It calls `sqrt` to generate the required behaviour according to the standard when a negative number is passed to `sqrt` (for example, set `errno` and/or raise a floating-point exception). The PXOR, UCOMISD, and JBE instructions test whether the argument is less than 0 and skip the call to `sqrt` if this isn't true.

Comment: But it's never using its result, that my question.

Comment: @Benoît Like I said, it doesn't need the result of the `sqrt`.  It's not calling `sqrt` to obtain the result. It's calling `sqrt` purely for its side effects, its error handling when the argument to `sqrt` is less than 0.

Comment: Which side effects ? The only I would think of would be setting errno.

Comment: @Benoît Isn't that enough? In C++11 it can also (or instead) generate an FE_INVALID floating-point exception. The compiler is simply leaving it up to the library implementation to handle this case.

Comment: @Benoît Compiler's job is also to recognize patterns and find an optimal way for computing the result. If the library's implementation is useless or equal to the assembly part, it'll probably just jump to the assembly.

Comment: But sqrt would calculate the root too, which leads to two calculations??

Comment: @TheTechel: In the cases where the argument >= 0, `std::sqrt` won't be called because it gets jumped over and the `sqrtsd` assembly instruction does the work. In the other cases (argument < 0), the `sqrtsd` instruction will be jumped over and `std::sqrt` will be called (with might or might not try to calculate the root of a negative number). So there will be at most one calculation.

Comment: @hoffmale Eh? Where do you see in the question that the `sqrtsd` instructions gets jumped over? It looks to me like that one executes unconditionally, it's only the call to `sqrt` that gets skipped. Which is still enough when optimising for the common case.

Comment: @hvd Admittedly, the `sqrtsd` does not get jumped over. But the `jbe` does jump over the `sqrt` library function when all is good, which should be the usual case. In the exceptional case that the argument is bad, it will perform both calculations (and fail both times, first with a floating point exception that is supposedly "ignored", then with the behaviour according to the standard as implemented in the library function). Apparently, the error condition is considered o be so unlikely or so fatal that the spurious calculation attempt does not matter. I also suppose that `sqrtsd` fails fast if